# Oracle Insert into partition binding the partition name in JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, partitioning

I'm using JDBC to insert lots of data into different partitions of a table. The table is system-partitioned which means I need to supply the partition name in the insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO T Partition P values (...);
```

I use a prepared statement to bind the values of the insert statement and now I'm wondering if it is possible to bind the partition name as well, cause I don't know which partition I need to insert until I see the actually data.

Comment: Have you tried it? What is the error message?

Comment: my guess is you can't for the same reason you cant bind a table name. you'll have to use string conactenation.

Comment: will using string concatenation for insert big performance hit compared to using prepared statement? I really have a huge data set need to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard Oracle partitioning scheme, You don't need to provide the partition name in an `INSERT` statement. One of the goal of Oracle partitioning is to be [application-transparent](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/schemaob.htm#CFAGCECI):

> From the perspective of an application, only one schema object exists. **DML statements require no modification** to access partitioned tables.

It is the exception, not the rule, to provide a partition in a statement: Oracle is smart enough to insert the row in the correct partition.

However, [System Partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/dom_idx.htm#ADDCI2801) requires that you provide the partition name.

Unfortunately, You can't specify a partition name dynamically with a bind variable since the partition name is an object name, and therefore needs to be known when the statement is parsed.

I suggest you use N prepared statement where N is the number of partitions inserted to. N is the minimum number of statements you will need.

Comment: System partitions doesn't have partition keys, being a system-partitioned table, the partition name has to be provided for all the partition related operations.

Comment: @wudong I didn't know of this new partition scheme. Always something to learn in Oracle!